# Third Party Store Credit Card Info?

Tags: api, pci-compliance, pci-dss

Does anyone know a third party that will store credit card and/or ACH information in a PCI compliant manner? So that it can viewed, and then manually processed?

I've looked at stripe.com but it looks like it tokenizes card data and I can't retrieve it. Another one is Square but I can't figure out if they offer this either?

So do you know of a service that securely stores PCI Compliant data so that I don't have buy an audit and do further work to secure my own server?

Is there such a thing as a PCI-Complant Data Storage service where you can login and get the information you need there?

Comment: Why did someone -1 this? Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: Probably because this question is off-topic.

Comment: And non-constructive; asking for recommendations or lists isn't appropriate for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont find such as service, because part of being PCI compliant is ensuring that anywhere else that receives raw data is also PCI compliant.

That would mean for the PCI compliant provider to return raw data to you, that *you* would need to be PCI compliant.  (And of course if that was the case why would you need a third party).